# EF - Generate script from previous migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I want to update database schema on production database. Usually in my development I just do `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`.

My question is how to generate script so I can manually read through the query before executing in production environment? I've tried `Update-Database -script` but it gave me `No pending explicit migrations`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: <initial-migration> -TargetMigration: <latest-migration>
```

Obviously replace `<initial-migration>` and `<latest-migration>` with the appropriate names of those migrations.

That should generate a script of all migrations at once.

More information [can be found here on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591621.aspx#script)